# BroadcastReceiver class that detects activity going onPause

Tags: android, android-broadcast

I'm sorry I know when we mix `BroadcastReceiver`s with activity life-cycle we cause the brain to have lots of errors and malfunction. I need help my brain stopped and my question is simple.

Is there a way to have `BroadcastReceiver` class that detect an activity going `onPause()` method ? if yes then how would that class be?

Comment: in on pause unRegister your broadcast and in onResume register it will solve your problem

Comment: If I right understand you can send Intent from onPause() callback and any BroadcastReceiver can catch it. Realy I fear to ask, why you need this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the only thing i can think of it on your activity send a costume broadcast intent that one of your receivers.

e.g:

action:

```
  public static final String CUSTOM_INTENT = "example.com.intent.action.ActivityGoingOnPause";
```

activity onPause:

```
  protected void onPause() {
     Intent i = new Intent();
     i.setAction(CUSTOM_INTENT);
     context.sendBroadcast(i);
  }
```

manifest:

```
    <receiver android:name=".YourReceiver" android:enabled="true">  
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="example.com.intent.action.ActivityGoingOnPause"></action>
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>
```

reciver:

```
 public class YourReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {
     @Override
     public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        if (intent.getAction().equals(YourActivity.CUSTOM_INTENT)) {
          //do your thing
        }
     }
 }
```

Hope this helps

Comment: @aljuaid86 also keep in mind this "You won't receive intents when paused, and this will cut down on unnecessary system overhead" origin: [site](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/BroadcastReceiver.html)

Answer (score 0):

Set a global variable like isActivityPaused in onPause and unset it in onResume of the activity and then check that variable and decide whether to send broadcast or not.